# SortBy in array of nested objects using underscore js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a data like this format.

```
    var data = [
       {id:1,
        format:'txt',
        array1:[
                {id:10, txt:3, Nm:A},
                {id:100, txt:2, Nm:B},
                {id:1000, txt:1, Nm:C}
               ]
       },
       {id:2,
        format:'vidz',
        array1:[
                {id:10,txt:5,Nm:X},
                {id:100,txt:9,Nm:Y},
                {id:1000,txt:6,Nm:Z}
               ]
       }
       ]
```

need to sortby "txt" using underscoreJs or any javascript method

```
var data = [
           {id:1,
            format:'txt',
            array1:[
                    {id:1000, txt:1, Nm:C},
                    {id:100, txt:2, Nm:B},
                    {id:10, txt:3, Nm:A}
                   ]
           },
           {id:2,
            format:'vidz',
            array1:[
                    {id:10,txt:5,Nm:X},
                    {id:1000,txt:6,Nm:Z},
                    {id:100,txt:9,Nm:Y}

                   ]
           }
           ]
```

How to sortBy ascending order for the "txt" inside of array1

Comment: have the arrays inside really different names?

Comment: It is an example format @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1):

You could use plain javascript an iterate the array and take then the inner array for sorting.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, format: 'txt', array1: [{ id: 10, txt: 3, Nm: 'A' }, { id: 100, txt: 2, Nm: 'B' }, { id: 1000, txt: 1, Nm: 'C' }] }, { id: 2, format: 'vidz', array1: [{ id: 10, txt: 5, Nm: 'X' }, { id: 100, txt: 9, Nm: 'Y' }, { id: 1000, txt: 6, Nm: 'Z' }] }];

data.forEach(a => a.array1.sort((a, b) => a.txt - b.txt));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```